Deleting and re-asking the same question
There was this question.
The asker themself deleted it.
And then asked it again.
When I tried to flag it as duplicate, the system said Cannot flag a deleted entity as a duplicate.
Now it seems to me that when a user themself deletes their own post and reposts it, it should be connectable as a duplicate.
In fact a case may be made that for the other case – mods/community delete it – this holds even more.
Part of this question should be a feature request on main-meta I guess; just thought I'd check here first what the position, view on this is.

I don't understand how something can be called a duplicate if the original is not available. In fact, any posts marked duplicate should be unmarked if the original was ever removed / deleted / hidden from the lowest privilege users. Otherwise it is a shell game to mark things. I've often been confused about why posts marked as duplicate or closed or whatever even continue to exist on the site? If they are unacceptable, wipe them out. But, I'm not a moderator, so what do I know?
